# Matlab: Markov chain for Pareto distribution

Tags: matlab, markov-chains

I am often using Markov chains to approximate first-order autoregressive processes AR(1). Now I would like to draw values from a Pareto distribution. Does anybody know how to construct a Markov chain for this type of distribution?
The point is that I approximate the infinite state space of the Pareto by a number n grid points. The time series of a simulation of the Markov Chain should then look 'similar' to the time series when simulating a Pareto distribution.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to draw from a Pareto distribution, why would you not just invert it's cumulative density, and evaluate it for random values between zero and one?

The cumulative density of a pareto distribution is rather simple, and inverting it is no problem (except for the input 1, which results in theoretical limit to infinity)

Of course this is only a workaround, and does not perform exactly what you asked (which I would gather is more of a theoretical exercise).

Comment: Hi Doness,thanks for your answer. You are right that this would help me draw initial values from a Pareto. However, what I am interested in is the dynamics. I want to approximate a time path for a variable that is Pareto distributed by allowing it to only take one of n values on a grid. Together with this grid one has to find a transition matrix of probabilities. I would appreciate any further help. Thanks!